# Singularity.gs: helpers _box-sizing.scss and _clearfix.scss not included into _helpers.scss

Tags: singularitygs

I'm currently working with singularity.gs v1.7.0 and I noticed that the helper files _box-sizing.scss, and _clearfix.scss, are not included into the _helpers.scss file. I did had the same experience with singularity.gs v1.6.2.

Here is how I'm including singularity.gs into my SASS code and also how I'm going around this issue:

```
@import "_singularitygs.scss";
// for some reason the content bellow wasn't called from inside singularity
@import "singularitygs/helpers/_box-sizing.scss";
@import "singularitygs/helpers/_clearfix.scss";
// end of missing libraries
```

Can somebody confirm if this is a bug or not, and what would be the preferable procedure to including these two files?

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a clear answer on the [documentation](https://github.com/at-import/Singularity/wiki/Output-Options).

Thank you